# mysql JOIN when one table has no entry

Tags: mysql, join, null

I have two tables:

player with player_id and name

team with player_id and team_id

Not all players have an entry in team.

I'm trying to create a query that, given a player_id, will return the name and null if the player_id is *not* found in the team table.

I've tried the various JOINs but I either get null, null or the name with the first team_id found in the table.

Thanks for any help

Comment: LEFT JOIN should do that

Comment: please give sample data for both tables (player and team).

Comment: Yeah, that works thanks. I thought I'd tried that but must have used it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Do this

```
SELECT p.PlayerID, t.PlayerID
FROM Player p
LEFT JOIN Team t
ON p.PlayerID = t.PlayerID
```

If you want null to be returned pick the t.PlayerID as p.PlayerID will not be null if it exists in Player

Your result will look like this

```
PlayerID   Player Name    TeamID    PlayerID
-------------------------------------------------
0001       John           NULL      NULL
```

As you can see it is the second PlayerID that is NULL not the first. Pick the second e.g. `WHERE t.PlayerID IS NULL`